# Angular directive, binding click event not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Controller:

```
.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'nicService','$cordovaSQLite', function ($scope, $state, nicService,$cordovaSQLite) {
    $scope.addRegister = function () {
        nicService.setData('nic', { nic: null });
        $state.go('addregister');
    };

    $scope.editregister = function (nic) {alert(nic)
        nicService.setData('nic', { nic: nic });//alert(nic);
        $state.go('addregister');
    };

    $scope.reg = {};
    $scope.searchRegister = function () {
        var query = "select * from Register ORDER BY codes ASC";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function (res) {
            var result = "";
            if (res.rows.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    if (res.rows.item(i).state == "A") {//background-color:#ddd;
                        result += "<div class='' style='border: #ddd 1px solid;'>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).codes+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).name+"</p></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).remark+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<i class='button button-small icon ion-edit' ng-click='editmemberdetail(" + res.rows.item(i).id + ")'></i><i class='button button-small icon ion-eye' ng-click='viewmemberdetail(" + res.rows.item(i).id + ")'></i></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                    } else {
                        result += "<div class='' style='border: red 1px solid;'>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).codes+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).name+"</p></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).remark+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><i class='button button-small icon ion-edit' ng-click='editmemberdetail(" + res.rows.item(i).id + ")'></i><i class='button button-small icon ion-eye' ng-click='viewmemberdetail(" + res.rows.item(i).id + ")'></i></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                    }

                }
            } else {
                result += "<div class='row' style='border:#ddd 0px solid;'>Register Panel Is Empty</div>";
            }
            $scope.reg.title = result;
        }, function (err) {//alert(err);
            console.error(err);
        });
    };
    $scope.searchtxtRegister = function () {
        var query = "select * from Register where codes like ? ORDER BY codes ASC";
        //$cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"delete from Member");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [$scope.reg.code]).then(function (res) {
            if (res.rows.length !== 0) {
                var result = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    if (res.rows.item(i).state == "A") {//background-color:#ddd;
                        result += "<div class='' style='border: #ddd 1px solid;'>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).codes+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).name+"</p></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).remark+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><i class='button button-small icon ion-edit' ng-click='editregister(" + res.rows.item(i).id + ")'></i></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                    } else {
                        result += "<div class='' style='border: red 1px solid;'>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).codes+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).name+"</p></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "<div class='row'>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><p>"+res.rows.item(i).remark+"</p></div>";
                        result += "<div class='.col col-50'><i class='button button-small icon ion-edit' ng-click='editregister(" + res.rows.item(i).id + ")'></i></div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                        result += "</div>";
                    }
                }
                $scope.reg.title = result;
            } else {
                $scope.searchRegister();
            }
        }, function (err) {
            alert(err);
            console.error(err);
        });
    };
}])
.directive('dirc', function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(attr.content, function () {
                element.html($parse(attr.content)(scope));
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }, true);
        }
    }
})
```

Html:

```
<dirc id="dirc" content="reg.title"></dirc>
```

Comment: Please format your code and explain a bit of what the problem actually is.

Comment: What is your problem? You just posted some code without a problem statement. Do you see errors in the console? Perhaps try to isolate the problem and create a jsfiddle/plnkr?